# How to print failure message in Ansible builtin.getent when user not found and continue with rest of tasks

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a playbook if a specific system user does not exist and make it fail and print a message if the user exists. Below the how I do the user check:

```
- name: 'Check system user'
  getent:
    database: passwd
    key: '{{USER}}'
  register: result
```

How do I make it fail and print message if user exists and make it continue with the rest of tasks if user does not exist?

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Q: **"*Fail and print a message if the user exists and continue with the rest of the tasks if the user does not exist.*"**

A: For example, given the variable

```yaml
USER: admin
```

The tasks below

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
    - assert:
        that: "{{ USER in getent_passwd }}"
        fail_msg: "User {{ USER }} does not exist."
        success_msg: "User {{ USER }} exists."
    - debug:
        msg: Continue
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [assert] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  msg: User admin exists.

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Continue
```

Test a missing user. For example

```yaml
USER: joker
```

The same tasks will fail and print the message

```yaml
TASK [assert] **************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: User joker does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I needed it the opposite way so I changed it to:

```
---
  - getent:
      database: passwd
  - assert:
      that: "{{ USER not in getent_passwd }}"
      fail_msg: "User {{ USER }} exists."
      success_msg: "User {{ USER }} does not exist."
  - debug:
      msg: Continue
```

And the result:

```
TASK [verify : assert] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "User missing does not exist."
}

TASK [verify : debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Continue"
}
```